# Preload/Cache video from network URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching, video, avasset

I am using SCPlayer (AVPlayer subclass) to play videos stored on a server

> SCPlayer.h
>   https://github.com/rFlex/SCRecorder/blob/master/Library/Sources/SCPlayer.h
>
> SCPlayer.m
>   https://github.com/rFlex/SCRecorder/blob/master/Library/Sources/SCPlayer.m

I would like to be able to preload videos before I play it with SCPlayer, I have tried this to store AVURLssets:

```
- (AVURLAsset *)addedOrPreloadedVideoAssetWithStringURL:(NSString *)urlString {
    if (![self.preloadedVideoAssets objectForKey:urlString]) {
        [self removePreloadedVideoAssetIfNeededAndAddKey:urlString];
        [self.preloadedVideoAssets setObject:[AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] options:nil] forKey:urlString];
    }
    return [self.preloadedVideoAssets objectForKey:urlString];
}
-(void)removePreloadedVideoAssetIfNeededAndAddKey:(NSString *)newKey {
    [self.preloadedVideoAssetsUrlKeys insertObject:newKey atIndex:0];
    if (self.preloadedVideoAssetsUrlKeys.count > PRELOAD_VIDEO_LIMIT) {
        for (int i = PRELOAD_VIDEO_LIMIT ; i < self.preloadedVideoAssetsUrlKeys.count ; i++) {
            [self.preloadedVideoAssets removeObjectForKey:[self.preloadedVideoAssetsUrlKeys objectAtIndex:i]];
            [self.preloadedVideoAssetsUrlKeys removeObjectAtIndex:i]; 
        }
    }
}
```

Usage :

```
NSString *sampleUrlString = @"http://download.wavetlan.com/SVV/Media/HTTP/H264/Other_Media/H264_test8_voiceclip_mp4_480x320.mp4";
AVURLAsset *asset = [self addedOrPreloadedVideoAssetWithStringURL:sampleUrlString];
[player setItemByAsset:asset];
```

This successfully allow me to play videos I have already played using **[self addedOrPreloadedVideoAssetWithStringURL:sampleUrlString]**, but calling it in advance won't pre-load videos (Reference App: Vine).

How can I achieve this ? (I Have AFNetworking ready if needed)